# Android: Fragments inside the ViewPager not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a Fragment. This fragment contains a view pager where the view page has multiple fragments. I can scroll the pages but seeing nothing even though getItem did call when scroll and initialised the fragment.

I have changed the code with support.v4.app.Fragment and support.v4.app.FragmentManager and change the main activity to FragmentActivity. In addition, I use getChildFragmentManager to the adapter but still can't showing anything.

I also change the line below to return true always but it can show the first fragment. Subsequent fragment aren't showing and behave badly when start paging it.

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return true;
}
```

Below is the code I implement the ViewPager.

```
public class AppsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private int appsSize;
private int appsPerPage = 12;
private Activity activity;

public AppsPagerAdapter (Activity activity1, FragmentManager manager, int size)
{
    super(manager);
    appsSize = size;
    activity = activity1;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    int offset = appsSize % appsPerPage;
    int pageExtra = (offset > 0)? 1: 0;
    return appsSize / appsPerPage + pageExtra;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt (AppPageFragment.PAGE_NUMBER_PARAMS, position);
    return Fragment.instantiate(activity, AppPageFragment.class.getName(), bundle);
}
```

}

Outer Fragment:

```
       @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_all_app, container, false);

        ViewPager appsPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_allapps);
        //adapter = new AppsPagerAdapter(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager(), GlobalData.getInstance().getApps().getAll().size());
        adapter = new AppsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), GlobalData.getInstance().getApps().getAll().size());
        appsPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        appsPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
        return view;
```

Comment: Can we see your pageChangeListener?

Comment: I found the problem, i need to check the objects in isViewFromObject properly

Comment: @LittleFunny what specifically? can you post how you changed your isViewFromObject class?

Comment: @CQM I actually had to remove the isViewFromObject method that was being overriden. Thanks for the answer, LittleFunny